# Mongodb : Mapreduce query filter positional operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a huge data set (in millions) in the following format :

```
{
  "userid" : "codejammer",
  "data" : [       
   {"type" : "number", "value" : "23748"},
   {"type" : "message","value" : "one"}
  ]
}
```

I want to get count of `message` with value `one` for `userid` - `codejammer`

The following is the mapreduce function I am using :
Map :

```
var map = function(){
   emit(this.data[0].value,1);
}
```

Reduce

```
var reduce = function(key,values){
    return Array.sum(values);
}
```

Options

```
var options = {
             "query":{"userid" : "codejammer",
                 "data.type" : "message"},
             "out" : "aggregrated"
            }
```

The mapreduce function executes successfully with the following output:

```
{
 "_id" : 23748,
  "value" : 1
}
```

But, I am expecting the following output :

```
{
 "_id" : one,
 "value" : 1
}
```

The `query` filter in options, is sending the entire array to map function even though I specifically ask for `data.type : "message"`

Is there any way to use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections) operator in `query` filter to get only the required item in array ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually would be better off doing this with [**`aggregate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). There is no need for mapReduce in this case and the aggregation framework runs as native code and will be much faster than running through the JavaScript interpreter:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Still makes sense to match the documents to reduce the set
    { "$match": {
        "userid": "codejammer",
        "data": { "$elemMatch": { 
            "type": "message", "value": "one" 
        }}
    }},

    // Unwind to de-normalize the array content
    { "$unwind": "$data" },

    // Filter the content of the array
    { "$match": {
        "data.type": "message",
        "data.value": "one"
    }},

    // Count all the matching entries
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Of course if you actually did only ever have one "message" inside your "data" array this becomes very simple:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match the documents you want
    { "$match": {
        "userid": "codejammer",
        "data": { "$elemMatch": { 
            "type": "message", "value": "one" 
        }}
    }},

    // Simply count the documents
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

But of course that is actually no different to this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "userid": "codejammer",
    "data": { "$elemMatch": { 
        "type": "message", "value": "one" 
    }}
}).count()
```

So while there is a way to do this with mapReduce, the other ways shown are much better. Especially in the newly released 2.6 version and upwards. In the newer versions the aggregation pipeline can make use of disk storage to handle very large collections.

But to get the count using [**`mapReduce`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) you were basically going about it the wrong way. The projection will not work as an input, so you need to take the element out of the results. I'm still going to consider that there could possibly be more than one matching value in your array even if that was not the case:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var userid = this.userid;
        this.data.forEach(function(doc) {
            if ( doc == condition )
                emit( userid, 1 ); 
        });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return values.length;
    },
    {
        "query": { 
            "userid": "codejammer",
            "data": { "$elemMatch": { 
                "type": "message", "value": "one" 
            }}
        },
        "scope": {
           "condition": {"type" : "message", "value" : "one"}
        },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

So in much the same way this "emits" a value for the common key when a document matching your criteria is found inside the data array. So you cannot project just the matching element, you get all of them and you filter in this way.

Since you are only expecting one result there is no point in actually outputting to a collection, so just send it out as one.

But basically, use the aggregation method if you have to do this.

Comment: There is a [limitation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions) to aggregate in terms of size. I need to do more complex mapreduc if this attempt is successful :)

Comment: @Neil, isn't the second `$match` phase redundant?

Comment: @AnandJayabalan No it is not. The purpose is to actually filter the elements of the array. But as I have said while extending this, if there is only actually one element then just count the results from `.find()`

Comment: @codejammer You will find that there is more than enough information here to accomplish what you want. As stated, from version 2.6 (released yesterday) the limitation no longer exists.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Thank you very much. That helped. But the only problem I see in the map reduce is - I should hardcode the document `{"type" : "message", "value" : "one"}` . Is there anyway I can take this document as a parameter ?

Comment: @codejammer as in just about everything you do not need to hard code anything, it's just data structures in code so even the function parts can actually be written as strings. But if it suits your sensibilities better I changed the listing to use a variable defined in the scope.

Comment: @codejammer Glad it was some help. But really, even for your own machine or even better stick it on a VM instance. But get a hold of 2.6 as it will devour this very easily and a lot faster than the mapReduce. Then convince your boss/dba/hosting provider to update.